# How to get the full file name from a TextFile variable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

The following code writes to a file named *test.txt* (In this case, in the current directory)

```
var
    F : TextFile;
begin
    AssignFile(F, 'test.txt');
    try
        Rewrite(F);
        //...
    finally
        CloseFile(F);
    end;
end;
```

How can I extract the full file name from the `F : TextFile` variable?

Comment: There seem to be two questions here. 1. How do I obtain the file name from a `TextFile` object? 2. How do I expand a relative filename into an absolute path? Which do you want us to answer? Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: There is a nuance here. The expansion of relative filename is done by the `TextFile` object when the file is opened. But the current directory may have changed by the time you ask the question. My advice is to perform the expansion before you call `AssignFile`, and pass the absolute file name. And then don't forget that file name so that you don't have to hope the `TextFile` object remembers it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right but my goal is to know the full file name assigned to the `TextFile` object. As you said "the current directory may have changed...", so I would like to know if `TextFile` object is storing the full file name somewhere. If not, I fully agree with your advice and I'll expand the path before calling `AssignFile`

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that the full file name would be stored by the Delphi object. After all, it would never even have used it. You'd need to get hold of the file handle and work from there.

Comment: Why not using TFileStream?

Comment: @RBA Yes, assignfile/rewrite/closefile are soooo 80's :)  - and so slow too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to solving this:

1. Obtain the file handle behind the `TextFile` object.
2. Get the file name from that handle.

For step 1 you use

```
var
  FileHandle: THandle;
....
FileHandle := TTextRec(F).Handle;
```

For step 2 the process is outlined on MSDN: [Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems like the OP asked for something else that I understood initially, I have the following answer instead:

```
{$J+}

USES Windows;

{$IFDEF UNICODE }
FUNCTION FileHandleToFileName(Handle : THandle) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,MAX_PATH+1);
    TRY
      SetLength(Result,GetFinalPathNameByHandle(Handle,@Result[LOW(Result)],LENGTH(Result),FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED))
    EXCEPT
      ON E:EExternalException DO SetLength(Result,0) ELSE RAISE
    END;
    IF COPY(Result,1,4)='\\?\' THEN DELETE(Result,1,4)
  END;
{$ELSE }
CONST FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED = $00000000;

FUNCTION GetFinalPathNameByHandleUndefined(hFile : THandle ; lpszFilePath : PChar ; cchFilePath,dwFlags : DWORD) : DWORD; stdcall;
  BEGIN
    StrPCopy(lpszFilePath,'');
    Result:=0
  END;

FUNCTION FileHandleToFileName(Handle : THandle) : STRING;
  TYPE
    TGetFinalPathNameByHandle   = FUNCTION(hFile : THandle ; lpszFilePath : PChar ; cchFilePath,dwFlags : DWORD) : DWORD; stdcall;

  CONST
    GetFinalPathNameByHandle    : TGetFinalPathNameByHandle = NIL;

  VAR
    Err                         : Cardinal;

  BEGIN
    IF NOT Assigned(GetFinalPathNameByHandle) THEN BEGIN
      GetFinalPathNameByHandle:=GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32'),'GetFinalPathNameByHandleA');
      IF NOT Assigned(GetFinalPathNameByHandle) THEN GetFinalPathNameByHandle:=GetFinalPathNameByHandleUndefined
    END;
    SetLength(Result,MAX_PATH+1);
    SetLength(Result,GetFinalPathNameByHandle(Handle,@Result[1],LENGTH(Result),FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED));
    IF COPY(Result,1,4)='\\?\' THEN DELETE(Result,1,4)
  END;
{$ENDIF }

FUNCTION FileNameOf(VAR TXT : TextFile) : STRING;
  VAR
    Handle      : THandle;

  BEGIN
    Handle:=TTextRec(TXT).Handle;
    Result:=FileHandleToFileName(Handle);
    IF Result='' THEN Result:=StrPas(TTextRec(TXT).Name)
  END;
```

I currently use UNICODE define to determine if Delphi already has an import definition for GetFinalPathNameByHandle - it can probably be fine tuned, if I find out which version actually implements this define.

Also note, that GetFinalPathNameByHandle is only valid for Windows Vista and on. If attempted to run on previous versions, it will fall back to simply extracting the file name that was ASSIGN'ed. If you need support for pre-Vista, you can look at the page that David linked to in order to get a version that should work on earlier versions.

Comment: I've tried your code on Delphi 5 and it raises 2 errors on compiling.
_[Error] Unit1.pas(59): HIGH cannot be applied to a long string_ on `@Result[LOW(Result)]` and _[Error] Unit1.pas(59): Undeclared identifier: 'FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED'_

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's true but if this code can help someone else, I think it should compile without errors. That's the only reason why I've replied

Comment: What's bizarre to my mind is that there is so much code simply to call an API function. It's not that hard. And I don't think we really need more bad code to import API functions. So yeah, if you are going to include code, it should work and be good.

Comment: @ExDev: Sorry - I don't have access to a D5 to test compile. Try the updated version - it should have eliminated the two problems you noticed.

Comment: thank you, it works on D5 now. I've upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
TTextRec(F).Name
```

to extract the ASSIGN'ed file name ('test.txt' in the above example) from a TextFile variable.

If by "full file name" you mean you want it including full directory, you'll need to tell us which version of Delphi you want it for, as the more modern ones have a lot of functions in this area that the earlier versions don't.

Comment: `SysUtils.ExpandFileName()` is there since a long time. `SysUtils.ExpandUNCFileName()` could also be used if UNC format is wanted.

Comment: @LURD: Since I am unsure as to the exact version that these functions were implemented, I didn't want to give them as options until I knew (and could verify) that that they were available in the version that the OP is using.

Comment: `ExpandFileName` is present in all versions of Delphi. In any case, you shouldn't feel the need to pander to users who have ancient versions. The job is not to help the asker, it is to answer the question. If an asker has an ancient version, that's their problem. It's not like either of these functions were added recently.

Comment: @HeartWare: In this moment I'm using an old Delphi 5, anyhow, I don't want to expand the path because the current directory may have changed. I would like to know if the `TextFile` object is storing the full file name somewhere

Comment: I think the only way to get that information is via the file handle and some WinAPI function. I haven't looked for such a function yet, though.

Comment: @ExDev: TextFile is only storing the value given to ASSIGN. If you don't want to expand the file before ASSIGN'ing it to TextFile, you need to ask Windows to do a "reverse lookup" on the handle to obtain the file name. Take a look at my 2nd answer for a function that should work on Delphi 5 (if you are running Windows Vista or later).

Comment: If you've decided that this answer does not address the question, as you state in your other answer, you should delete it I think.